# How to add a border color when Router Link is activated form the menu of menuitem in react with typescript and MUI (5.15.14)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, menuitem

This is my button with Menu along with menu Items .

```
  <Button
        id="demo-customized-button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'demo-customized-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        variant="contained"
        disableElevation
        onClick={handleClick}
        endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
      >
        setting 
      </Button>
      
      <Menu
        id="demo-customized-menu"
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'demo-customized-button',
        }}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        <MenuItem  onclick={closehandle} component={routerLink} to="/">Home</MenuItem>
      />
```

Below is the  routerLink component passing to menuitem

```
import {
  NavLink as RouterLink,
  NavLinkProps as RouterLinkProps,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const routerLink = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, RouterLinkProps>((itemProps, ref) => 
   {
    return <RouterLink ref={ref} {...itemProps} role={"MenuItem"} />;
  },
);
```

When router link isActive(Home) then how to apply border color?

Comment: What is `RouterLink` and how are you styling your components? See [mcve].

Comment: @Drew -  below component what  i'm serving as component={routerLink}. as import {
  NavLink as RouterLink,
  NavLinkProps as RouterLinkProps,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const routerLink = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, RouterLinkProps>((itemProps, ref) => 
   {
    return <RouterLink ref={ref} {...itemProps} role={"ManuItem"} />;
  },
);

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include that information for a more complete [mcve]? Please also clarify what you are trying to add a border color to. Right now there's too much guesswork, the post needs more specific details.

Comment: When the Router Link isActive then i want to apply for that active link an any border color?

Comment: So you want to apply a border style to the `RouterLink` component? Or the `MenuItem` component? Some other component? What existing styling code/logic/etc is already being applied to these components?

Comment: yes MenuItem component of property  component={routerLink} i want to apply border style..